# How to read selected row from a shown pandas dataframe as output in ipywidgets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ipywidgets

I have a `pandas` dataframe displayed through a `widgets.Output()` in a simple dashboard. What I want to do is read what row the user clicked so I can further process data. The following is an example of the dataframe shown through the `ipywidget`.

[image: Dataframe example]

Basically, I want to know either the index or the value when the user selects a given row. Say:

[image: User pressed the M23 row]

Is there a way I can read this?

An example of the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as widgets

df = pd.DataFrame(index=['J21','D21','J22','M23'])
df['Last'] = [4.10,4.38,4.63,4.90]
df['Wtd'] = [-0.02,0.02,0.02,0.01]
df['Mtd'] = [-0.08,-0.02,-0.01,0.01]
df['3mth'] = [-0.10,0.25,0.50,0.73]
df['Ytd'] = [-0.19,0.16,0.38,0.52]

out = widgets.Output()
with out:
    display(df)

out
```

Basically when I show out on my code, it prints the df as an ipywidget. I now want to read when a user click on a given row (say M23), so I can show additional information for that particular item in another ipywidget. Is that doable?

Thanks very much!

Comment: you could show minimal working code which would show how and what you create. And we could run it to test ideas (so put it as text, not image). At this moment I have no idea what you have and I can only suggest to read documentation for `events` and `binding` functions to events. For better suggestion I would have to build minimal working code and test information from documentation - but ... there are other questions which gives minimal working code and I go answer on other questions.

Comment: Hi furas, thanks for your comment. Im adding on your suggestion a few lines of code. Im new to ipywidgets and pandas, but hopefully that helps to see whether it can be done.